# How to access array object using vuex?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js

I'm making a chrome extension using Vuejs.

Some of my store are as follows.

```
// states
export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
....
obj1: {
      inObj1: {
        a: [],
        b: [],
        c: []
      },
      inObj2: {
        a: [],
        b: [],
        c: []
      },
      inObj3: {
        a: [],
        b: [],
        c: []
      }
    }
}
```

And this state is being changed to mutation after receiving http response within action.

```
// actions
// 1st action (update A)
....
axios.post(url, {
    from: (Date.now() - 5000000).toString(),
    to: (Date.now() + 5000000).toString(),
    queries: [query]
  }, { withCredentials: true })
    .then(ret => {
      commit(types.UPDATE_A, {
        data: ret.data,
        product: payload.product,
        env: payload.env
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('in promise: ', err)
    })

// 2nd action (update B)
  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(ret => {
      commit(types.UPDATE_B, {
        product: payload.product,
        env: state.env.pub,
        data: ret.data.demandMap,
        src: state.sources.b,
        memberNo: payload.memberNo
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
// 3th action
  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(ret => {
      commit(types.UPDATE_C, {
        product: payload.product,
        env: state.env.pub,
        data: ret.data.demandMap,
        src: state.sources.c,
        memberNo: payload.memberNo
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
```

```
// mutations
// After updating A, update B and C within for loop with A's response.
...
case state.products.vs.code: {
        for (let i = 0; i < tables.rows.length; i++) {
          state.billing.Obj1[state.sources.a].push({
            memberNo: tables.rows[i][memIdx],
            product: payload.product,
            env: payload.env,
            source: 'A',
            charge: tables.rows[i][chargeIdx]
          })
          getB(tables.rows[i][memIdx], payload.product, payload.env)
        }
        break
      }
// 
...
```

By using the Vue Devtools I can see that there are objected being pushed into the array, but their `a` and `b`, `c` is `undefined`.

`console.log('process done : ', this.obj[this.productName].a) -> undefined`
Please refer to the fact that the variable name may not be accurate because the code above was partially modified for questions.

Why can't I access it within the mute but other getter and Vue? Help me.

Comment: Please edit your post with your mutations.